# Как в gulp работать с несколькими html файлами?

Tags: html, css, gulp

Как в gulp работать с несколькими html файлами, чтобы автообновление работало на всех этих файлах? (browsersync подключен)

Answer (score 7):

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
     baseDir: 'app'
   },
 })
})

gulp.task('watch', 'browserSync', function(){
         gulp.watch("ваш путь к файлам/*.html").on("change", reload);
});
```